# apt upgrade stuck on kbd and console-setup

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade, dpkg

This is what happens when I try to upgrade a remote machine via an ssh terminal session that does not normally run X:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.108ubuntu15.5) ...
Couldn't interpret _XKB_RULES_NAMES property
Use defaults: rules - 'base' model - 'pc105' layout - 'us'
Error loading new keyboard description
bin/setupcon: 803: bin/setupcon: bin/../bin/ckbcomp: not found
dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.5); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kbd:
 kbd depends on console-setup | console-setup-mini; however:
  Package console-setup is not configured yet.
  Package console-setup-mini is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package kbd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup-linux:
 console-setup-linux depends on kbd (>= 1.15-1ubuntu3); however:
  Package kbd is not configured yet.
 console-setup-linux depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.5); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 keyboard-configuration
 console-setup
 kbd
```

Hmm, I wonder where the message `Couldn't interpret _XKB_RULES_NAMES property` comes from, and is it significant?

Perhaps `/etc/default/keyboard` is the problem?

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

That looked ok. Here is the problem again:

```
$ setxkbmap en
Couldn't interpret _XKB_RULES_NAMES property
Use defaults: rules - 'base' model - 'pc105' layout - 'us'
Error loading new keyboard description
```

Suggestions?

Comment: *4 not fully installed or removed* is the problem.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. My question is how to fix the problem.

Comment: Reinstall those packages and later remove them if they aren't needed.

Comment: Tried that. The problem never goes away

Comment: Sorry but no... If you ever tried and succeeded you wouldn't be having that error message now.

Comment: That is tautology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem. Somehow uninstalling `perl` cleared the logjam:

```
sudo apt remove perl keyboard-configuration console-setup-linux console-setup kbd
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install perl
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt upgrade -f
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

Comment: My fix worked on another system!

Comment: Holy crap, thank you! This was a nightmare!